# How pass marker title to String

Tags: java, android

I built an app with google maps, that displays 40 markers titles loaded from MySQL, and I need to convert `marker.title` into a string

I tried the following but couldn't get it to work:

```
 public void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title) {
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(title);
    final String TimeNot = String.valueOf(markerOptions.title(title));
```

Answer (score 0):

You already set the title of the marker here:

```
markerOptions.title(title);
```

As the doc says: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions

```
   String getTitle()
    Gets the title set for this MarkerOptions object.
```

You can use `markerOptions.getTitle()` to get the title of that marker, and it will be stored as String.

So, you can do this:

```
 public void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title) {
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(title);
    final String TimeNot = markerOptions.getTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **markerOptions.getTitle()** to get the title of the marker

```
public void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title) {
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(title);
    final String TimeNot = markerOptions.getTitle();
```

### or

```
 public void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title) {
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(title);
    final String TimeNot = title;
```